# How can I make new attribute for html5 tags?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make new attribute for html5 tags?

I'm writing Javascript code and would like to use these attributes as variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `data-` attributes:)  [Data-Attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), [Custom data-Attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)
for eg:

```
<div class="user" data-name="Stack" data-city="London"
     data-lang="js" data-food="Bacon">asdasd</div>
```

then you can access in Jquery using [Jquery.data() method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) like this

```
alert($('.user').data('name'))//will print Stack
```

see demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8py6q/)